# Find value in matrix starting from two columns value

Tags: r, loops, matrix, indices

I have a dataframe `df` with two columns:

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c(3,7,2,6,14,9,3,2,1,5,7,9,5,13,2,8),
                var2 = c(5,7,3,1,5,8,3,6,5,1,4,7,5,7,8,1))
```

Note that var1 and var2 can have also different values and not necessarily (1:10)

```
 var1 var2
    3    5
    7    7
    2    3
    6    1
    14   5
    9    8
    3    3
    2    6
    1    5
    5    1 
    7    4
    9    7
    5    5
    13   7
    2    8 
    8    1
```

and a matrix with these values:

```
x = matrix(1:10, nrow = 8, ncol = 15)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] 
[1,]    1    9    7    5    3    1    9    7    5     3     1     9     7     5     
[2,]    2   10    8    6    4    2   10    8    6     4     2    10     8     6     
[3,]    3    1    9    7    5    3    1    9    7     5     3     1     9     7     
[4,]    4    2   10    8    6    4    2   10    8     6     4     2    10     8     
[5,]    5    3    1    9    7    5    3    1    9     7     5     3     1     9     
[6,]    6    4    2   10    8    6    4    2   10     8     6     4     2    10     
[7,]    7    5    3    1    9    7    5    3    1     9     7     5     3     1     
[8,]    8    6    4    2   10    8    6    4    2    10     8     6     4     2
```

starting from `var1` and `var2` values, I would like to use them as matrix indices and find the corrisponding value in the matrix for creating a new column `var3` so that in this case `var3` would be:

```
var3 = c(1,5,1,1,9,2,9,4,5,3,2,1,7,3,6,7)
```

and to have a final df like:

```
   var1 var2 var3
    3    5   1
    7    7   5
    2    3   1
    6    1   1
    14   5   9
    9    8   2
    3    3   9
    2    6   4
    1    5   5
    5    1   3
    7    4   2
    9    7   1
    5    5   7
    13   7   3
    2    8   6
    8    1   7
```

Comment: `x[as.matrix(rev(df))]`

Comment: What if var1 and var2 are two of many columns in a df? How can I specifically select them?

Comment: You would select by name, e.g. `x[as.matrix(df[c("var2", "var1")])]`.  The order is important where the first column is the row index, and the second the column index.  You could also select by position but by name is safer.

Comment: It gives error. It says `Subscript 'i' is a matrix, it must be of type logical`

Comment: If your question is find value in a matrix, then you shouldn't convert it to a tibble.  These are entirely different objects.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a new column to your data frame `var3`.
Then, Matrix `x` can be used to determine the `var3` elements with respect to `var1` and `var2`. You can do this using a simple `for loop` in R using an `if statement`. Here is the sample code:

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c(3,7,2,6,14,9,3,2,1,5,7,9,5,13,2,8),
                var2 = c(5,7,3,1,5,8,3,6,5,1,4,7,5,7,8,1))
x = matrix(1:10, nrow = 8, ncol = 15)

# Adding a new column to the dataframe.
df <- cbind(df, var3 = NA)

# Reading the indices from the matrix and replacing values in the third column.
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  df[i,3] = x[df[i,2],df[i,1]]
}
```

If you call the data frame you will have:

```
     var1 var2 var3
1     3    5    1
2     7    7    5
3     2    3    1
4     6    1    1
5    14    5    9
6     9    8    2
7     3    3    9
8     2    6    4
9     1    5    5
10    5    1    3
11    7    4    2
12    9    7    1
13    5    5    7
14   13    7    3
15    2    8    6
16    8    1    7
```